# How can I make DatagramPacket code on swift?

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, datagram

So I have this java(android) code that uses DatagramPacket to send and receive udp messages.

```
DatagramSocket ds = null;
ds = new DatagramSocket();
            ds.setSoTimeout(30000);
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(IP_ADDRESS);
            DatagramPacket dp;
            dp = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg.getBytes(), udpMsg.length(), serverAddr, UDP_SERVER_PORT);

            ds.send(dp);

            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            ds.receive(receivePacket);
            response = new String(receivePacket.getData(), "UTF-8");

            String str = new String(receivePacket.getData(), "UTF-8");
            data1 = str.substring(0,receivePacket.getLength());


private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String sender = intent.getStringExtra("sender");
            Bundle msg = intent.getBundleExtra("message");
        }
    };

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("UDPBroadcast"));
```

Now, I want to do the same thing on iOS. I currently have this code.

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://\(host):\(connectPort)")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
       let socket = manager.defaultSocket

       socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
           print("socket connected")
       }

       socket.on("sender") {data, ack in

           print("sender data: \(data)")
       }

       socket.connect()
```

But it gives me this logs

```
SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connect
SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: sender
SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting]
SocketIOClient{/}: Joining namespace /
SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
SocketManager: Adding engine
SocketManager: Manager is being released
SocketIOClient{/}: Client is being released
SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://255.255.255.255:6000
SocketEngine: Handshaking
SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://255.255.255.255:6000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1
SocketEnginePolling: Could not connect to the server.
SocketEngine: Could not connect to the server.
SocketEngine: Engine is being released
```

The server I'm calling is a golang server and it's self-signed. The android code executes fast. I'm new to iOS development and sockets. If you could recommend other pods that can do socket connection other than SocketIO, please include sample code please or link to it.

UPDATE:
This is my current code

```
import Foundation
import CocoaAsyncSocket
import SocketIO
import Starscream

class UDPSocket: NSObject, GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate{
    var udpSock : GCDAsyncUdpSocket!
    let listenPort: UInt16 = 6000
    let data = "test".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let host = "255.255.255.255"
    let connectPort: UInt16 = 6000
    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://255.255.255.255:6000")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("init")
        udpSock = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)

        do{
            try udpSock!.bind(toPort: listenPort)
            try udpSock!.enableBroadcast(true)
        }catch _ as NSError {
            print("Issue with d to Port")
            return
        }

        let socket = manager.defaultSocket

        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
        }

        socket.on("sender") {data, ack in

            print("sender data: \(data)")
        }

        socket.connect()

    }

    func sendUDP(){
        do {
            try udpSock!.beginReceiving()
            udpSock.send(data, toHost: host, port: connectPort, withTimeout: 60, tag: 0)
        }catch _ as NSError {
            print("Issue with sending to Port: ")
            return
        }
    }


    public func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceive data: Data, fromAddress address: Data, withFilterContext filterContext: Any?) {
        let str = NSString(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("received: \(String(describing: str))")

        if let data1 = str?.intValue{
            if(data1 > 0){
                print("data1 isNum: \(data1)")
            }
        }

    }

    public func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didSendDataWithTag tag: Int) {

        print("didSendDataWithTag")
    }

    public func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didNotSendDataWithTag tag: Int, dueToError  error: Error?) {

        print("didNOTSendDataWithTag err: \(String(describing: error))")
    }

    public func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didNotConnect error: Error?) {
        print("didNOTConnect")
    }

    public func udpSocketDidClose(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, withError error: Error?) {
        print("DidCloseSocket")
    }

    @objc  public func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didConnectToAddress address: Data) {
        let str = NSString(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("didConnectToAddress addr: \(String(describing: str))")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `SocketManager`  is released due to its local scope. You should create global object of manager.

like

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.log(true)])
```

Comment: But that's the same thing I use on the android version

Comment: You have to create global object of  `SocketManager`  beneath the your class

Comment: something like `var socketManager: SocketManager()`?

Comment: `let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://\(host):\(connectPort)")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])` are you getting my point ?

Comment: i've added my code. but I still can't connect to my server

Answer (score 0):

Hi @rminaj this is basically what I am doing

```
class YourClass {

  var manager : SocketManager!
  var socket : SocketIOClient!

  func establishConnection() {
    self.manager = SocketManager(socketURL: yourUrl, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    self.socket = self.manager.defaultSocket
  }
}
```

Comment: after trying your code, the error now says `The Internet connection appears to be offline.` do you think I need to configuration something on Info.plist but I already got `App Transport Security Settings`

Comment: Not sure. Can you access the URL somehow _outside_ the app, like `ping $url`?

Comment: I can't ping the url. But, I could call it on android

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `SocketIO` client. It is a library for `WebSocket` protocol which is over `tcp`.

Use [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket) instead.

Its easy as

`udpSocket = UDPClient(address: ADDR, port: PORT)`

Or else you could use the `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26818254/2861108)

```
func setupConnection(){
    var error : NSError?
    socket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    socket.bindToPort(PORT, error: &error)
    socket.connectToHost(SERVER_IP, onPort: PORT, error: &error)
    socket.beginReceiving(&error)
    send("ping")
}

func send(message:String){
   let data = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
   socket.sendData(data, withTimeout: 2, tag: 0)
}
```

Possible other answers: [How to implement UDP client and send data in Swift on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295486/how-to-implement-udp-client-and-send-data-in-swift-on-iphone)

Comment: I'm already using `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` and already getting a result. But I still need to receive another data from the socket. If you look at the java code, it's the `intent.getStringExtra("sender")`

Comment: It seems that I mixed up stuff. I think I need to use `NSNotificationCenter` to get the second value.